# Asp.Net 4.0 Ajax Postback w/ Redirect produces Double Escaped Url

Tags: ajax, redirect, updatepanel, postback, asp.net-4.0

I started noticing this problem after my session expired and I would click a button to perform an Ajax Postback inside of an UpdatePanel. ASP would catch the expired session and redirect me to the home page, however the URL it sends me to is escaped and ASP would refuse the request

Url: `%2fDefault.aspx%3fReturnUrl%3d%252fMyPage.aspx%253fCurrentDate%253d2013-04-19%26CurrentDate%3d2013-04-19`.

Error: `The request filtering module is configured to deny a request that contains a double escape sequence.`

To narrow the problem I setup a test case of Postbacks inside and outside of an UpdatePanel.

**Test.aspx:**

```
<asp:UpdatePanel runat="server" ID="upTest">
    <ContentTemplate>
        <asp:LinkButton runat="server" ID="lnkAjaxPostbackTest" OnClick="PostbackTest">AJAX Postback Test</asp:LinkButton><br />
        <asp:LinkButton runat="server" ID="lnkAjaxPostbackRedirectTest" OnClick="PostbackRedirectTest">AJAX Redirect Test</asp:LinkButton>
    </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
<asp:LinkButton runat="server" ID="lnkPostbackTest" OnClick="PostbackTest">Postback Test</asp:LinkButton><br />
<asp:LinkButton runat="server" ID="lnkPostbackRedirectTest" OnClick="PostbackRedirectTest">Redirect Test</asp:LinkButton>
```

**Test.aspx.cs**

```
protected void PostbackTest(object sender, EventArgs e) {
   var x = 3;
}
protected void PostbackRedirectTest(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    Response.Redirect("~/Default.aspx");
}
```

**Results**
The regular (non-Ajax) postbacks worked correctly in all cases (even when the session expired). However, the AJAX Redirect Test would send me to `/%2fDefault.aspx` when my session was active and the AJAX Postback Test would send me to `/%2fDefault.aspx%3fReturnUrl%3d%252fTest.aspx` if the session expired.

So why is this happening? Perhaps javascript is handling the redirect and it isn't performing `decodeURIComponent`? I couldn't find anything in the HTTP response that indicates that a redirect should occur.

Answer (score 0):

The culprit is the ToolkitScriptManager in the AjaxControlToolkit assembly. I replaced it with the regular ScriptManager provided in ASP and the problem instantly vanished.

In summary: AjaxControlToolkit.ToolkitScriptManager + Ajax Postback + Redirect => Doubly Escaped Uris